# Should I mark up my normal rate when using a freelancing site which takes a cut?

Tags: united-states, freelancing, websites, billing

My rate for direct freelancing projects is X.  A client has asked me to use Upwork, which takes a 10% cut.  Should I increase my rate to X + 11%, putting the overhead on the client, or keep the same rate and take the overhead myself, or somewhere in between?

I do not know if Upwork charges the hiring party anything, but that seems likely.

My first thought is that, since the client has requested this third party which is not strictly necessary, he should eat the cost of it.  When a client wanted to use PayPal a few years back, I added the 2% overhead to the bill (depositing a check would have cost me nothing, after all).  However, part of the reason I can charge a higher rate as a contractor is because I am my own marketing department; working with an organization such as a consulting company or freelancing site mitigates that.

Is there a generally-accepted practice, or is this wide open to opinion?  For context, I'm in the U.S., and consult for database design and a business intelligence.

Comment: If they asked they should pay.

Comment: You might get a better answer on freelancing.stackexchange, the site for freelancers

Comment: I usually split the money such that he incurs half the cut, and I incur half. Also, using PayPal is risky, what if the client doesn't pay you? Freelancer and Upwork both have a dispute resolution service. For me, the 10% of Upwork is reasonable for all the protection and convenience services it offers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on how badly you need your client. Standard operating procedure in a situation like this is to **inform your client** that Service, Tool, Strategy or whatever that they'd like to use will add a cost/overhead of X% which will be reflected in your rate as Y. **Then let the client decide whether he's okay with that increased cost.**

A negotiation can sometimes follow to determine how close to X your Y will be. Major factors to consider there are you relationship with the client (past/present/future), the value of the tool or service to the contractor, impact on planning and so on. But typically, clients will be aware that extras cost more and won't make a problem of it. Some will decide not to take the cost and drop the requirement.

Almost all clients will appreciate a contractor who's transparent in his pricing. A rare few will reject you outright for having the nerve to charge your costs through to them and tell them about it while they wouldn't bat an eye if you just gave a higher base rate. But you probably don't want to work with the latter group anyway.

If you ever get the impression from a client that he won't take this well or is otherwise less than professional, but you'd still be happy to take his money, just add the cost to your rate and avoid a lot of potential drama.

---

In your specific case the service your client wants to use will likely impact you in no meaningful way other than changing the source of the payments and charging you 10% for it. The advantage for the client is presumably simplified administration and he should assume the cost.

Comment: I agree that the decision is better left to a client.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere See my response in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27172531#27172531)

Answer (score 7):

In my opinion you should make the rate you require- the additional costs mandated by the client should be their costs of doing business. So add the markup to cover- there is no reason you should bear the cost of doing this business.

Answer (score 1):

You should add all extra costs to your bill, either factored into your rate or separate. I usually separate them for transparency. In saying that my rate also widely differs depending on the individual client, so it would be easy enough to just add it without bothering.

It depends on the relationship with the client, if it's a long standing client with an agreeable relationship I might consider covering the costs. With a new client, it's important to be upfront and transparent with the money. And it's not usually a good idea to give discounts or anything else until you have an established relationship with them. Unless of course you're desperate for work.